# Why is style property undefined here?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

Why is style property of span undefined in this code.I can't figure out the answer.Thank you in advance.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function func(){
                var span1 = document.createElement("span").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Yellow"));;
                document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(span1);
                span1.style.color = "Yellow";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick = "func();">Click</button>
    <p id = "p1">Main paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do a console.log(span1), and you will spot the problem. It's "appendChild" that is returning `undefined`, when it's "createElement" that should return the element.

Comment: Step one of debugging: `console.log(span1)` and see that it's not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `appendChild` is the node you appended. This is a **text node**. Text nodes don't have style, only element nodes do.

You need to store the return value of `createElement` instead, and then use that value to both append to and be appended.

```
const span1 = document.createElement("span");
span1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Yellow"));
document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(span1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the appended Child. In your case it is a `textNode`. You cannot add style to a text node. You need a node of type Element, like `span`. In your case it is a simple fix:

```js
function func() {
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Yellow"));
  document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(span1);
  span1.style.color = "Yellow";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func();">Click</button>
<p id="p1">Main paragraph</p>
```

If you `console.log(span1)` in your code, you can see NodeType is 3. Generally, you need NodeType 1 for Element Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your snippet, `span1` should be the **span object/element**, only then it can modify `style` properties. **Text Nodes** have no `style` properties.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function func(){
                var span1 = document.createElement("span");
                span1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Yellow"));;
                document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(span1);
                span1.style.color = "Yellow";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick = "func();">Click</button>
    <p id = "p1">Main paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **span1** not storing an object of span it stores the text Element

```
const span1 = document.createElement("span");
 span1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Yellow"));
span1.style.color = "Yellow";
```